# Return List<String> from Spring WebClient's onStatus response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

Using Spring's `WebClient` I make a call to a remote system. If the remote system answers with HTTP 422, then it also returns a list of strings in its response body which I would like to return as a `List<String>`.

This is my current code, but the IDE tells me:

```
Required type: Mono<? extends Throwable>
Provided: Mono<List<String>>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that List<String> conforms to Throwable
```

Is it possible to achieve what I'm looking for?

```java
webClient
  .post()
  .uri("/validation/{reference}", reference)
  .body(Mono.just(request), ValidationRequest.class)
  .retrieve()
  .onStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, response -> {
      // extract response body as List<String> and return it...
      return response.bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {});
  })
  .block();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct as `onStatus` needs to return an object of type `Mono<? extends Throwable>`. Instead of that method, you can use the `onErrorResume` method to handle exceptions of type `WebClientResponseException` differently, as in check if the status code is `422` and if so, parse the response body into a `List<String>`. The code could look something like below:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
webClient
  .post()
  .uri("/validation/{reference}", reference)
  .body(Mono.just(request), ValidationRequest.class)
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {})
  .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> {
        try {
            return ex.getRawStatusCode() == 422 ? 
                    Mono.just(objectMapper.readValue(ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), new TypeReference<List<String>>() {})) : 
                        Mono.error(ex);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException jsonException) {
            return Mono.error(jsonException);
        }
    })
  .block();
```